# Java Regex to match Vietnamese chars

Tags: java, regex

I have to write a regex to restrict a input field, that only allow Vietnamese chars, English chars and digits. I know how to restrict English chars (`[a-zA-Z]`) and digits (`[0-9]`), but don't know how to restrict Vietnamese chars.

Can anyone give me a java regex to match Vietnamese chars?

Vietnamese chars are Like: ể, ứ (Edit: but i don't know all of them. Otherwise, i can use`[a-list-of-chars]`, or maybe there is a range, like `[a-d]` instead of `[abcd]`)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Vietnamese Alphabet

The *intersection* of the Vietnamese alphabet and English alphabet (i.e. whatever that is common between the 2 alphabets) is the alphabet of English minus `f`, `j`, `w` and `z`.

In Vietnamese, `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `y` are considered vowels.

Apart from those, Vietnamese also use several other characters with diacritics. Below list the uppercase of the character (the lowercase version has a 1-character-to-1-character mapping, unlike ß in German):

- Consonant:

  ```
  Đ: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D WITH STROKE
  ```
- Vowels:

  ```
  Ă: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH BREVE
  Â: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX
  Ê: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLE
  Ô: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH CIRCUMFLEX
  Ơ: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH HORN
  Ư: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH HORN
  ```

Vietnamese has 6 tones, except for the first tone, the other 5 tones are indicated by another diacritic on the **vowels**. The tonal diacritics are acute `á`, grave `à`, hook `ả`, tilde `ã` and dot below `ạ`. Since there are (6 + 6) vowels times 5 tones with diacritics, plus 6 vowels already with diacritic on the first tone, there are 66 glyphs of vowels with diacritic(s):

Here is the list of all (67) consonants and vowels with diacritic(s):

```
  Á À Ã Ả Ạ
Ă Ắ Ằ Ẳ Ẵ Ặ
Â Ấ Ầ Ẩ Ẫ Ậ
Đ
  É È Ẻ Ẽ Ẹ
Ê Ế Ề Ể Ễ Ệ 
  Í Ì Ỉ Ĩ Ị
Ô Ố Ồ Ổ Ỗ Ộ
Ơ Ớ Ờ Ở Ỡ Ợ
  Ó Ò Õ Ỏ Ọ
Ư Ứ Ừ Ử Ữ Ự
  Ú Ù Ủ Ũ Ụ
  Ý Ỳ Ỷ Ỹ Ỵ
```

These characters spread across different Latin blocks in Unicode. I handpicked these characters from Character Map, and I had to be careful not to pick characters which are visually identical to the character above. To be sure, we can print the names of the characters and check that they are Latin character rather than Greek or Cyrillic.

```
String VIETNAMESE_DIACRITIC_CHARACTERS = "ẮẰẲẴẶĂẤẦẨẪẬÂÁÀÃẢẠĐẾỀỂỄỆÊÉÈẺẼẸÍÌỈĨỊỐỒỔỖỘÔỚỜỞỠỢƠÓÒÕỎỌỨỪỬỮỰƯÚÙỦŨỤÝỲỶỸỴ";

for (char c: VIETNAMESE_DIACRITIC_CHARACTERS.toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println(c + ": " + Character.getName(c));
}
```

### Combining character

Vietnamese Input methods such as Unikey has 2 modes: single code point mode ("Unicode dựng sẵn"), and combining mark mode ("Unicode tổ hợp").

As an example, for the same character `ợ` (U+1EE3), there can be several ways to specify it:

- As single code point (1 code point): `ợ`
- As a combination of `ơ` (U+01A1) and combining dot below (U+0323) (2 code points): `ợ`
- As a combination of `o`, combining hook (U+031B), and combining dot below (U+0323) (3 code points): `ợ`

You can copy these character into the console of the browser and check its length:

```
["ợ","ợ","ợ"].forEach(function (e) {console.log(e.length);})
```

If you want to match all those 3 variations above, you must list all possible combinations and permutations to specify the character, **and** you would have to do this for all the characters with diacritics as listed above, **and** in both uppercase and lowercase.

Easy enough?

Even if you answer yes, your code will become an unmaintainable mess that no one can understand.

### [Canonical Equivalence](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-18.html)

Since there are more than one ways to specify the same text `ợ`, without any transformation, it is not possible to compare `ợ` and `ợ` to be equal.

```
"ợ".equals("ợ") --> false
```

Unicode Standard therefore define all 3 ways to specify `ợ` above as *canonically equivalent*, and also define methods to normalize a string for comparison purpose.

### Java Pattern support for Canonical Equivalence

The reference implementation of `Pattern` class (by Oracle, widely used on Windows and other platforms) has (partial) support for canonical equivalence matching using `Pattern.CANON_EQ` mode. It is extremely buggy to the point of unusable as seen in [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4867170) and [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7080302) bug report. At the time of writing, this bug has been there on all version since `CANON_EQ` is "supported", and it is not likely to be fixed any time soon. However, it is not totally broken, and we can still make use of whatever currently offered by the option.

### Solution

Below is the construction of the `Pattern` for matching Vietnamese + English alphabet, :

```
String VIETNAMESE_DIACRITIC_CHARACTERS 
        = "ẮẰẲẴẶĂẤẦẨẪẬÂÁÀÃẢẠĐẾỀỂỄỆÊÉÈẺẼẸÍÌỈĨỊỐỒỔỖỘÔỚỜỞỠỢƠÓÒÕỎỌỨỪỬỮỰƯÚÙỦŨỤÝỲỶỸỴ";

Pattern p =
    Pattern.compile("(?:[" + VIETNAMESE_DIACRITIC_CHARACTERS + "]|[A-Z])++",
                    Pattern.CANON_EQ |
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE |
                    Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
```

The additional flags `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE` are used to make the pattern matches case-insensitively for all Unicode characters. `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` alone only makes the pattern matches case-insensitively for characters in US-ASCII charset.

Note that the order of the characters in `VIETNAMESE_DIACRITIC_CHARACTERS` is significant. I don't recommend changing the order of the characters unless you understand the implication.

**The input should be normalized with Canonical Decomposition (NKD) or Canonical Composition (NKC) before matching is performed on it.** It ensures that the combining marks are in a canonical order.

Regardless of whether the input is preprocessed with Canonical Composition or Canonical Decomposition, the result *looks* the same. Running the code in the appendix should return *visually identical* result for the second and the third output:

> `Bạn chính là tác giả của Wikipedia Mọi người đều có thể biên tập bài ngay lập tức chỉ cần nhớ vài quy tắc Có sẵn rất nhiều trang trợ giúp như tạo bài sửa bài hay tải ảnh Bạn cũng đừng ngại đặt câu hỏi Hiện chúng ta có bài viết và thành viên`
>
> `Bạn chính là tác giả của Wikipedia Mọi người đều có thể biên tập bài ngay lập tức chỉ cần nhớ vài quy tắc Có sẵn rất nhiều trang trợ giúp như tạo bài sửa bài hay tải ảnh Bạn cũng đừng ngại đặt câu hỏi Hiện chúng ta có bài viết và thành viên`

### Failed attempts

Here are some failed attempts, which will be used to explain why the regex is constructed as shown above.

**Attempt 1**

```
String VIETNAMESE_DIACRITIC_CHARACTERS 
        = "ẮẰẲẴẶĂẤẦẨẪẬÂÁÀÃẢẠĐẾỀỂỄỆÊÉÈẺẼẸÍÌỈĨỊỐỒỔỖỘÔỚỜỞỠỢƠÓÒÕỎỌỨỪỬỮỰƯÚÙỦŨỤÝỲỶỸỴ";

Pattern p =
    Pattern.compile("[A-Z" + VIETNAMESE_DIACRITIC_CHARACTERS + "]++",
                    Pattern.CANON_EQ |
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE |
                    Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
```

*Why don't we include `A-Z` into a single character class instead of putting it in a separate character class and alternate with the diacritic character class?*

Nope, the result is broken when we try to match on the Canonical Decomposition of the input string. The diacritics are not matched at all.

> `Ba n chi nh la ta c gia cu a Wikipedia Mo i ngu o i đe u co the bie n ta p ba i ngay la p tu c chi ca n nho va i quy ta c Co sa n ra t nhie u trang tro giu p nhu ta o ba i su a ba i hay ta i a nh Ba n cu ng đu ng nga i đa t ca u ho i Hie n chu ng ta co ba i vie t va tha nh vie n`

**Attempt 2**

```
String VIETNAMESE_DIACRITIC_CHARACTERS 
        = "ÁÀÃẢẠĂẮẰẲẴẶÂẤẦẨẪẬĐÉÈẺẼẸÊẾỀỂỄỆÍÌỈĨỊÓÒÕỎỌÔỐỒỔỖỘƠỚỜỞỠỢÚÙỦŨỤƯỨỪỬỮỰÝỲỶỸỴ";

Pattern p =
    Pattern.compile("(?:[" + VIETNAMESE_DIACRITIC_CHARACTERS + "]|[A-Z])++",
                    Pattern.CANON_EQ |
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE |
                    Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
```

*The diacritic characters are declared in a character class, so the code should behave the same when I change the order of the character... Right?*

Nope, some results are broken when we try to match on the Canonical Decomposition of the input string.

> `Bạn chính là tác giả của Wikipedia Mọi ngươ i đê u có thê biên tạ p bài ngay lạ p tư c chỉ câ n nhơ vài quy tă c Có să n râ t nhiê u trang trơ giúp như tạo bài sư a bài hay tải ảnh Bạn cũng đư ng ngại đạ t câu hỏi Hiẹ n chúng ta có bài viê t và thành viên`

### Explanation

The reference implementation (Oracle) implements `Pattern.CANON_EQ` mode by picking out characters in the expression which can be expanded into multiple characters under Canonical Decomposition and perform a textual transformation of the regex. Then, the expression will be compiled as per normal.

The first pass to transform the regex doesn't parse the expression properly, so it exhibits crazy behavior for very simple matching as seen in the bug reports above.

Fortunately, `Pattern` class spits out the regex after the transformation if there is an unmatched `(` in the regex. Therefore, we can just add `(` at the end to trigger `PatternSyntaxException` and look at the transformed regex string.

Let's mess up the solution regex above and see what is the regex string that enters the compilation step:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 596
(?:(?:[Đ]|Ắ|Ắ|Ắ|Ằ|Ằ|Ằ|Ẳ|Ẳ|Ẳ|Ẵ|Ẵ|Ẵ|Ặ|Ặ|Ặ|Ặ|Ặ|Ặ|Ă|Ă|Ấ|Ấ|Ấ|Ầ|Ầ|Ầ|Ẩ|Ẩ|Ẩ|Ẫ|Ẫ|Ẫ|Ậ|Ậ|Ậ|Ậ|Ậ|Ậ|Â|Â|Á|Á|À|À|Ã|Ã|Ả|Ả|Ạ|Ạ|Ế|Ế|Ế|Ề|Ề|Ề|Ể|Ể|Ể|Ễ|Ễ|Ễ|Ệ|Ệ|Ệ|Ệ|Ệ|Ệ|Ê|Ê|É|É|È|È|Ẻ|Ẻ|Ẽ|Ẽ|Ẹ|Ẹ|Í|Í|Ì|Ì|Ỉ|Ỉ|Ĩ|Ĩ|Ị|Ị|Ố|Ố|Ố|Ồ|Ồ|Ồ|Ổ|Ổ|Ổ|Ỗ|Ỗ|Ỗ|Ộ|Ộ|Ộ|Ộ|Ộ|Ộ|Ô|Ô|Ớ|Ớ|Ớ|Ớ|Ớ|Ớ|Ờ|Ờ|Ờ|Ờ|Ờ|Ờ|Ở|Ở|Ở|Ở|Ở|Ở|Ỡ|Ỡ|Ỡ|Ỡ|Ỡ|Ỡ|Ợ|Ợ|Ợ|Ợ|Ợ|Ợ|Ơ|Ơ|Ó|Ó|Ò|Ò|Õ|Õ|Ỏ|Ỏ|Ọ|Ọ|Ứ|Ứ|Ứ|Ứ|Ứ|Ứ|Ừ|Ừ|Ừ|Ừ|Ừ|Ừ|Ử|Ử|Ử|Ử|Ử|Ử|Ữ|Ữ|Ữ|Ữ|Ữ|Ữ|Ự|Ự|Ự|Ự|Ự|Ự|Ư|Ư|Ú|Ú|Ù|Ù|Ủ|Ủ|Ũ|Ũ|Ụ|Ụ|Ý|Ý|Ỳ|Ỳ|Ỷ|Ỷ|Ỹ|Ỹ|Ỵ|Ỵ)|[A-Z])++(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ^
```

As we can see, the engine grab all the characters which can expand under Canonical Decomposition, take it outside the character class and build an alternation.

It is still not very clear what is happening with the same characters repeating in alternation, so I will insert space between every character:

> `( ? : ( ? : [ Đ ] | A ̆ ́ | Ă ́ | Ắ | A ̆ ̀ | Ă ̀ | Ằ | A ̆ ̉ | Ă ̉ | Ẳ | A ̆ ̃ | Ă ̃ | Ẵ | A ̣ ̆ | Ạ ̆ | Ặ | A ̆ ̣ | Ă ̣ | Ặ | A ̆ | Ă | A ̂ ́ | Â ́ | Ấ | A ̂ ̀ | Â ̀ | Ầ | A ̂ ̉ | Â ̉ | Ẩ | A ̂ ̃ | Â ̃ | Ẫ | A ̣ ̂ | Ạ ̂ | Ậ | A ̂ ̣ | Â ̣ | Ậ | A ̂ | Â | A ́ | Á | A ̀ | À | A ̃ | Ã | A ̉ | Ả | A ̣ | Ạ | E ̂ ́ | Ê ́ | Ế | E ̂ ̀ | Ê ̀ | Ề | E ̂ ̉ | Ê ̉ | Ể | E ̂ ̃ | Ê ̃ | Ễ | E ̣ ̂ | Ẹ ̂ | Ệ | E ̂ ̣ | Ê ̣ | Ệ | E ̂ | Ê | E ́ | É | E ̀ | È | E ̉ | Ẻ | E ̃ | Ẽ | E ̣ | Ẹ | I ́ | Í | I ̀ | Ì | I ̉ | Ỉ | I ̃ | Ĩ | I ̣ | Ị | O ̂ ́ | Ô ́ | Ố | O ̂ ̀ | Ô ̀ | Ồ | O ̂ ̉ | Ô ̉ | Ổ | O ̂ ̃ | Ô ̃ | Ỗ | O ̣ ̂ | Ọ ̂ | Ộ | O ̂ ̣ | Ô ̣ | Ộ | O ̂ | Ô | O ̛ ́ | Ơ ́ | Ớ | O ́ ̛ | Ó ̛ | Ớ | O ̛ ̀ | Ơ ̀ | Ờ | O ̀ ̛ | Ò ̛ | Ờ | O ̛ ̉ | Ơ ̉ | Ở | O ̉ ̛ | Ỏ ̛ | Ở | O ̛ ̃ | Ơ ̃ | Ỡ | O ̃ ̛ | Õ ̛ | Ỡ | O ̛ ̣ | Ơ ̣ | Ợ | O ̣ ̛ | Ọ ̛ | Ợ | O ̛ | Ơ | O ́ | Ó | O ̀ | Ò | O ̃ | Õ | O ̉ | Ỏ | O ̣ | Ọ | U ̛ ́ | Ư ́ | Ứ | U ́ ̛ | Ú ̛ | Ứ | U ̛ ̀ | Ư ̀ | Ừ | U ̀ ̛ | Ù ̛ | Ừ | U ̛ ̉ | Ư ̉ | Ử | U ̉ ̛ | Ủ ̛ | Ử | U ̛ ̃ | Ư ̃ | Ữ | U ̃ ̛ | Ũ ̛ | Ữ | U ̛ ̣ | Ư ̣ | Ự | U ̣ ̛ | Ụ ̛ | Ự | U ̛ | Ư | U ́ | Ú | U ̀ | Ù | U ̉ | Ủ | U ̃ | Ũ | U ̣ | Ụ | Y ́ | Ý | Y ̀ | Ỳ | Y ̉ | Ỷ | Y ̃ | Ỹ | Y ̣ | Ỵ ) | [ A - Z ] ) + + (`

We can see that the bunch of same character repeating is not really the same - they are different sequences to represent the same character.

With the same method, let us analyze the regex in attempt 2 to see why it fails.

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 596
(?:(?:[Đ]|Á|Á|À|À|Ã|Ã|Ả|Ả|Ạ|Ạ|Ă|Ă|Ắ|Ắ|Ắ|Ằ|Ằ|Ằ|Ẳ|Ẳ|Ẳ|Ẵ|Ẵ|Ẵ|Ặ|Ặ|Ặ|Ặ|Ặ|Ặ|Â|Â|Ấ|Ấ|Ấ|Ầ|Ầ|Ầ|Ẩ|Ẩ|Ẩ|Ẫ|Ẫ|Ẫ|Ậ|Ậ|Ậ|Ậ|Ậ|Ậ|É|É|È|È|Ẻ|Ẻ|Ẽ|Ẽ|Ẹ|Ẹ|Ê|Ê|Ế|Ế|Ế|Ề|Ề|Ề|Ể|Ể|Ể|Ễ|Ễ|Ễ|Ệ|Ệ|Ệ|Ệ|Ệ|Ệ|Í|Í|Ì|Ì|Ỉ|Ỉ|Ĩ|Ĩ|Ị|Ị|Ó|Ó|Ò|Ò|Õ|Õ|Ỏ|Ỏ|Ọ|Ọ|Ô|Ô|Ố|Ố|Ố|Ồ|Ồ|Ồ|Ổ|Ổ|Ổ|Ỗ|Ỗ|Ỗ|Ộ|Ộ|Ộ|Ộ|Ộ|Ộ|Ơ|Ơ|Ớ|Ớ|Ớ|Ớ|Ớ|Ớ|Ờ|Ờ|Ờ|Ờ|Ờ|Ờ|Ở|Ở|Ở|Ở|Ở|Ở|Ỡ|Ỡ|Ỡ|Ỡ|Ỡ|Ỡ|Ợ|Ợ|Ợ|Ợ|Ợ|Ợ|Ú|Ú|Ù|Ù|Ủ|Ủ|Ũ|Ũ|Ụ|Ụ|Ư|Ư|Ứ|Ứ|Ứ|Ứ|Ứ|Ứ|Ừ|Ừ|Ừ|Ừ|Ừ|Ừ|Ử|Ử|Ử|Ử|Ử|Ử|Ữ|Ữ|Ữ|Ữ|Ữ|Ữ|Ự|Ự|Ự|Ự|Ự|Ự|Ý|Ý|Ỳ|Ỳ|Ỷ|Ỷ|Ỹ|Ỹ|Ỵ|Ỵ)|[A-Z])++(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ^
```

Insert space between every character:

> `( ? : ( ? : [ Đ ] | A ́ | Á | A ̀ | À | A ̃ | Ã | A ̉ | Ả | A ̣ | Ạ | A ̆ | Ă | A ̆ ́ | Ă ́ | Ắ | A ̆ ̀ | Ă ̀ | Ằ | A ̆ ̉ | Ă ̉ | Ẳ | A ̆ ̃ | Ă ̃ | Ẵ | A ̣ ̆ | Ạ ̆ | Ặ | A ̆ ̣ | Ă ̣ | Ặ | A ̂ | Â | A ̂ ́ | Â ́ | Ấ | A ̂ ̀ | Â ̀ | Ầ | A ̂ ̉ | Â ̉ | Ẩ | A ̂ ̃ | Â ̃ | Ẫ | A ̣ ̂ | Ạ ̂ | Ậ | A ̂ ̣ | Â ̣ | Ậ | E ́ | É | E ̀ | È | E ̉ | Ẻ | E ̃ | Ẽ | E ̣ | Ẹ | E ̂ | Ê | E ̂ ́ | Ê ́ | Ế | E ̂ ̀ | Ê ̀ | Ề | E ̂ ̉ | Ê ̉ | Ể | E ̂ ̃ | Ê ̃ | Ễ | E ̣ ̂ | Ẹ ̂ | Ệ | E ̂ ̣ | Ê ̣ | Ệ | I ́ | Í | I ̀ | Ì | I ̉ | Ỉ | I ̃ | Ĩ | I ̣ | Ị | O ́ | Ó | O ̀ | Ò | O ̃ | Õ | O ̉ | Ỏ | O ̣ | Ọ | O ̂ | Ô | O ̂ ́ | Ô ́ | Ố | O ̂ ̀ | Ô ̀ | Ồ | O ̂ ̉ | Ô ̉ | Ổ | O ̂ ̃ | Ô ̃ | Ỗ | O ̣ ̂ | Ọ ̂ | Ộ | O ̂ ̣ | Ô ̣ | Ộ | O ̛ | Ơ | O ̛ ́ | Ơ ́ | Ớ | O ́ ̛ | Ó ̛ | Ớ | O ̛ ̀ | Ơ ̀ | Ờ | O ̀ ̛ | Ò ̛ | Ờ | O ̛ ̉ | Ơ ̉ | Ở | O ̉ ̛ | Ỏ ̛ | Ở | O ̛ ̃ | Ơ ̃ | Ỡ | O ̃ ̛ | Õ ̛ | Ỡ | O ̛ ̣ | Ơ ̣ | Ợ | O ̣ ̛ | Ọ ̛ | Ợ | U ́ | Ú | U ̀ | Ù | U ̉ | Ủ | U ̃ | Ũ | U ̣ | Ụ | U ̛ | Ư | U ̛ ́ | Ư ́ | Ứ | U ́ ̛ | Ú ̛ | Ứ | U ̛ ̀ | Ư ̀ | Ừ | U ̀ ̛ | Ù ̛ | Ừ | U ̛ ̉ | Ư ̉ | Ử | U ̉ ̛ | Ủ ̛ | Ử | U ̛ ̃ | Ư ̃ | Ữ | U ̃ ̛ | Ũ ̛ | Ữ | U ̛ ̣ | Ư ̣ | Ự | U ̣ ̛ | Ụ ̛ | Ự | Y ́ | Ý | Y ̀ | Ỳ | Y ̉ | Ỷ | Y ̃ | Ỹ | Y ̣ | Ỵ ) | [ A - Z ] ) + + (`

Notice that `A ̂ | Â` comes before `A ̂ ̀ | Â ̀ | Ầ` in the regex. This means that `A ̂` will be tried first on the input `Ầ` (`A ̂ ̀`), and the repetition will end when it fails to match anything in the next iteration.

Since the order of the alternation is important, as a general rule, between 2 strings where one string is a prefix of the other, the longer string should go first in the alternation. In our case, we need to place the characters with more diacritics before the character with less or without diacritics.

Same problem with attempt 1:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 589
(?:[A-ZĐ]|Ắ|Ắ|Ắ|Ằ|Ằ|Ằ|Ẳ|Ẳ|Ẳ|Ẵ|Ẵ|Ẵ|Ặ|Ặ|Ặ|Ặ|Ặ|Ặ|Ă|Ă|Ấ|Ấ|Ấ|Ầ|Ầ|Ầ|Ẩ|Ẩ|Ẩ|Ẫ|Ẫ|Ẫ|Ậ|Ậ|Ậ|Ậ|Ậ|Ậ|Â|Â|Á|Á|À|À|Ã|Ã|Ả|Ả|Ạ|Ạ|Ế|Ế|Ế|Ề|Ề|Ề|Ể|Ể|Ể|Ễ|Ễ|Ễ|Ệ|Ệ|Ệ|Ệ|Ệ|Ệ|Ê|Ê|É|É|È|È|Ẻ|Ẻ|Ẽ|Ẽ|Ẹ|Ẹ|Í|Í|Ì|Ì|Ỉ|Ỉ|Ĩ|Ĩ|Ị|Ị|Ố|Ố|Ố|Ồ|Ồ|Ồ|Ổ|Ổ|Ổ|Ỗ|Ỗ|Ỗ|Ộ|Ộ|Ộ|Ộ|Ộ|Ộ|Ô|Ô|Ớ|Ớ|Ớ|Ớ|Ớ|Ớ|Ờ|Ờ|Ờ|Ờ|Ờ|Ờ|Ở|Ở|Ở|Ở|Ở|Ở|Ỡ|Ỡ|Ỡ|Ỡ|Ỡ|Ỡ|Ợ|Ợ|Ợ|Ợ|Ợ|Ợ|Ơ|Ơ|Ó|Ó|Ò|Ò|Õ|Õ|Ỏ|Ỏ|Ọ|Ọ|Ứ|Ứ|Ứ|Ứ|Ứ|Ứ|Ừ|Ừ|Ừ|Ừ|Ừ|Ừ|Ử|Ử|Ử|Ử|Ử|Ử|Ữ|Ữ|Ữ|Ữ|Ữ|Ữ|Ự|Ự|Ự|Ự|Ự|Ự|Ư|Ư|Ú|Ú|Ù|Ù|Ủ|Ủ|Ũ|Ũ|Ụ|Ụ|Ý|Ý|Ỳ|Ỳ|Ỷ|Ỷ|Ỹ|Ỹ|Ỵ|Ỵ)++(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ^
```

Since the alternations are formed after the original character class, the vowels in `[A-Z]` will be tried first, leading to the repetition terminating early when it encounters a stray combining mark.

### Reference

- [Vietnamese Alphabetical System](http://vietunicode.sourceforge.net/charset/vietalphabet.html)
- [Common Vietnamese Input Method](http://vietunicode.sourceforge.net/inputmethod.html)
- [Optimized Unicode Composition and Decomposition](http://www.icu-project.org/docs/papers/optimized_unicode_composition_and_decomposition.html)

### Appendix

Below is the source code of the testing program.

[**Demo on ideone**](http://ideone.com/EDkkj4)

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.text.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String VIETNAMESE_DIACRITIC_CHARACTERS 
            = "ẮẰẲẴẶĂẤẦẨẪẬÂÁÀÃẢẠĐẾỀỂỄỆÊÉÈẺẼẸÍÌỈĨỊỐỒỔỖỘÔỚỜỞỠỢƠÓÒÕỎỌỨỪỬỮỰƯÚÙỦŨỤÝỲỶỸỴ";
        /*
        for (char c: VIETNAMESE_DIACRITIC_CHARACTERS.toCharArray()) {
            System.out.println(c + ": " + Character.getName(c));
        }
        */

        String tests[] = new String[3];
        tests[0] = 
            "Bạn chính là tác giả của Wikipedia!\n" + 
            "Mọi người đều có thể biên tập bài ngay lập tức, chỉ cần nhớ vài quy tắc." +
            "Có sẵn rất nhiều trang trợ giúp như tạo bài, sửa bài hay tải ảnh." + 
            "Bạn cũng đừng ngại đặt câu hỏi.\n" +
            "Hiện chúng ta có 1.109.446 bài viết và 406.782 thành viên.";

        tests[1] =
            Normalizer.normalize(tests[0], Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        /*
        for (char c: tests[1].toCharArray()) {
            System.out.printf("%04x ", (int) c);
        }
        */  
        tests[2] =
            Normalizer.normalize(tests[0], Normalizer.Form.NFC);

        try {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:[" + VIETNAMESE_DIACRITIC_CHARACTERS + "]|[A-Z])++", Pattern.CANON_EQ | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);

            for (String t: tests) {
                Matcher m = p.matcher(t);
                while (m.find()) {
                    System.out.print(m.group() + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The bug with canonical equivalence has been fixed from Java 9. Therefore, you should be able to freely specify the characters in the character class any order you want if your application drops support for older version of Java.

Answer (score -1):

Regex does not care if its Vietnamese, Danish and so on.

```
System.out.println("Biểuthức".matches("\\D+")); // true
```

Edited:

```
// You have to add every Vietnamese chars in the below regex:

 System.out.println("Biểuthức".matches("[\\w ểứ]*")); // true
```

Comment: i only what to math Vietnamese chars

Comment: So u want to find ể and ứ?

Comment: yes, i have to write a regex to restrict a input field, that only allow Vietnamese chars, English chars and digits

Comment: in fact, what i want, is that "every Vietnamese chars", where to find?

Comment: You can't tell regex to find a special language characters, without telling the expression which special characters is should look after. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_alphabet